# How to avoid paste to system clipboard when use Emacs For Mac OS X?

Tags: osx, gui-emacs

When use [Emacs For Mac OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com/), copy a string from browser(E.g. `B`) then paste into it, it works.

But if use `ciw`(vim mode) on a string(it's the same as copy a string inside the tool, E.g. `A`), then `Ctrl + v` to paste the previous string again, it will show the one cut in the tool(`A`). I hope it can take `B` here.

This case doesn't happened when use emacs in terminal.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the steps you are taking, e.g. do you copy a string when in vim mode? Also, what is the behaviour you would like to see?

Comment: @Lindydancer I added some more description. E. g. `B` and `A`. It seems `A` overwrite `B`(from outside) in the GUI tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to guess what you mean ;-) and suggest using `M-x yank-pop` (bound by default to `M-y` normally) instead of `M-x yank` (bound to `s-v` and `C-y` by default in my setup on Mac OS, but possibly `Ctrl + v` is bound to `yank` in your case).

The exact behavior of the `yank-pop` may depend on the version of Emacs you're using (this function was updated not so long ago). You can read more about this command usage in installed Emacs with `C-h f yank-pop` and `M-x info-apropos <RET> yank-pop`.

On Emacs 28.0.50, after hitting `M-y` (`M-x yank-pop`) I currently get this nicely looking kills (cuts) history selection interface in the minibuffer: [image]

[Use `C-s` and `C-r` to switch to the next/previous item.]

Another way to use `M-x yank-pop` is to call it right after pasting with the `M-x yank` command (`s-v`/`C-y` binding), such as:

1. `C-y` inserts the most recent item from the kill ring.
2. Then `M-y` replaces just inserted item with the earlier available killed item (going further back in the kill history on each `M-y` hit).

Hope my guess is right and this answer helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Your guess is right and it's very helpful to me.

Comment: @Miantian, I'm glad to hear it.